# How do I get the latest version of Mingw-w64?

Tags: apt

When I try to apt-get Mingw-w64, the latest version is not the latest stable release (5.0.3). The libVLC project I’m working on insists on version 5 or higher. How do I force the installation of a specific version?

Comment: Did you run `apt update` first? If yes, then it may be that the Ubuntu repos just don't have the latest version, and you may need to get it elsewhere, like from a PPA.

Comment: Using bleeding edge versions is not good for end-users. Ubuntu is not Arch, we do not repair our car while driving. For whom you are developing your program? Most users have Ubuntu LTS, they care about stability. So they can't install your program if you release it in public. I recommend to use the latest LTS versions.